# Xpath differentiate two attributes with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, attributes, muenchian-grouping

```
select="$BCRs/BCR[count(. | $BCRs/BCR[@bss = @bss][1]) = 1]"
```

I need the two `@bss` to refer to each `$BCRs/BCR`.

I'm using the Muenchian technique to get the first element with each value of the attribute. However, I can't use keys so I have to check the attributes this way. How can I make the `@bss` refer to different nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand why you can't use keys, but I think you can't solve that in XSLT 1.0 then with a single expression, instead you can use an approach like

```
<xsl:for-each select="$BCRs/BCR">
  <xsl:variable name="group" select="$BCRs/BCR[@bbs = current()/@bbs]"/>
  ... select="$group[1]"  ...
```

Comment: I'm trying something like that `<xsl:variable name="BCRs-unique">
   <xsl:for-each select="$BCRs/BCR">
    <xsl:copy-of select=".[count(. | $BCRs/BCR[@bss = current()/@bss][1]) = 1]"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>`